# Commutative ring $A$, saturated set $S$ and $\bar{S}$

Tags: commutative-algebra, localization

Let $A$ be a commutative ring. A multiplicatevely closed subset $S$ in $A$ is called *saturated* if for all $a,b \in A$, $ab \in S$ implies $a\in S$ and $b\in S$.

> Prove that
> (i) For a multiplicatevely closed subset $S\subseteq A$, prove that $\bar{S} =\{a\in A$ | there exists $b\in A $ with $ab\in S\}$ is a multiplicatevely closed set,
> (ii) $S\subseteq \bar{S}$,
> (iii) $ \bar{\bar{S}}=S$, i.e., $\bar{S} $ is saturated.

Work: I have done (i). For (ii) I took one element in $S$ but I have no reason to believe why it must always lie in $\bar{S}$, can you explain why it should always hold?

For (iii) I tried to prove that $\bar{S}$ is saturated but failed: if I have $ab\in \bar{S}$ and I have to prove that $a$, $b$ lie in $\bar{S}$.
$ab\in \bar{S}$ implies that there exists $c\in A$ such that $abc\in \bar{S}$. $abc\in \bar{S}$ implies that there exists $d$ in $A$ such that $abcd \in S$. But how would I prove that $a, b\in \bar{S}$?

So, please suggest some hints for (ii) and (iii).

Comment: For (ii), what if you take $b=1$? For (iii), you haven't written down the claim correctly. Start there. $\overline{\overline{S}}$ is the set of elements $a\in A$ so that there's some $b\in A$ with $ab\in \overline{S}$, or equivalently those $a\in A$ so that there's some $b,c\in A$ with $abc\in S$. Do you see what to do now?

Comment: @Hank (ii) is done.

Comment: @Hank (iii) is also done. Thanks!